# How to use tensorflow xla aot mode to build a CNN model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

I used xla aot build a CNN model, it compiled with no errors, but when execute the binary, a segmentation fault raised. and when i change the model to an fully connected network, it works fine. this seems a tensorflow bug, anyone have built the CNN model using xla aot?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this flag

```
tfcompile_flags = "--xla_cpu_multi_thread_eigen=false",
```

inside the `tf_library` rule.